# Trigonometric integral without using tangent substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

How can we solve integrals of rational functions of trigonometric functions like $$\int \frac{1}{3 \sin{x} + 5\cos{x}}dx$$ without tangent (Weierstrass) substitution? I assume that the polynomials are linear polynomials of sine or cosine.

Comment: Which polynomials do you have in mind?

Comment: $$3\sin+5\cos=\sqrt{3^2+5^2}...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\displaylines{{1\over 3\sin x+5\cos x}={3\sin x-5\cos x\over 9 \sin^2x-25\cos^2 x}\\ =
{3\sin x \over 9-34 \cos^2 x}+{5\cos x\over 25-34\sin^2 x}}$$
Then substituting $u=\cos x$ in the first term and $v=\sin x$ in the second results in
$$\int {1\over 3\sin x+5\cos x}=-3\int {du\over 9-34u^2}+5\int {dv\over 25-34v^2}$$

Comment: The second denominator is $34\sin^2x-25$, otherwise great solution.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks, I will correct  the answer. I have promised myself not to type on my mobile phone  while watching tennis game on TV.

Answer (score 0):

Divide both numerator and dinominator by sq(3^2+ 5^2)
then we can write the denomiator as sin(x+t) where tant=5/3